# Passing input values randomly while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have stored procedure, using this Sp am inserting data into employee table and am passing values as input parameters like ,

```
create procedure sp_inputvalues
@ename varchar(50),
@enum int,
@address varchar(100),
@sal int
as
begin

insert into employee(ename,enum,address,salary)values(@ename,@enum,@address,@sal) 

end
```

To execute the Sp ,

```
exec sp_inputvalues 'venkat',1252,'nrl',20000
```

but now my requirement is i need to pass the input values in random order like,

```
exec sp_inputvalues 1252,'venkat','nrl',20000
```

if I pass as above format the stored procedure should work and the stored procedure should be remain same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the names of the parameters

```
exec sp_inputvalues 
    @enum = 1252, 
    @ename = 'venkat', 
    @address = 'nrl', 
    @sal = 20000;
```